# Differentiating $4^{x^{x^x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-towers

### $4^{x^{x^x}}$

Hi, I came across this question and would like to check whether I have it done correctly:
$e^{x^3}\ln4=4^{x^3}(3\ln4\cdot x^2)$
is this the correct solution?

Comment: Do you know to to differentiate $x^x$?

Comment: hi, the first one. sorry I have no idea how to format multiple power properly.

Comment: I have not done $x^x$ before, but would it be $x^x(lnx+1)$?

Comment: Use `$4^{x^{x^x}}$` to show $4^{x^{x^x}}$.

Comment: The derivative of $n^{x^{x^x}}$ looks like this $$n^{x^{x^x}}x^{x^x+x-1}\ln 4(x (\ln x)^2+x\ln x +1)$$

Comment: It is not the correct answer. Note that the conventional meaning of $a^{b^c}$ is $a^{(b^c)}$.

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592377/what-is-the-derivative-of-fx-x2x3x4x5x6x7x

Comment: @MXYMXY $\ln 4  \rightarrow \ln n$.

Comment: @Kaka you Are you OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kick start
$$(f(x)^{g(x)})'=(\exp(g(x)\ln f(x))'=(\exp(g(x)\ln f(x))(g'(x)\ln f(x)+g(x)\cdot\frac1{f(x)}\cdot f'(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

Your order is wrong, as generally $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$(as noted by @AndréNicolas)

You should use that $(4^{f(x)})'=\ln 4 \times 4^{f(x)}f'(x)$.

Note that the derivative of $x^{g(x)}=x^{g(x)-1}(x \ln x g'(x) +g(x))$

As you pointed out, $(x^x)'=x^x(\ln x+1)$.

You can use these formulae to calculate $4^{x^{x^x}}$, which is  $$4^{x^{x^x}}x^{x^x+x-1}\ln 4(x (\ln x)^2+x\ln x +1)$$

**NOTE**

You need not memorize the second formula, but it is not too difficult to calculate this, and you appear to be aware of how to do it.